# Looping prompt in Javascript until condition is met

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to use a while loop in order to show a prompt message that prompts the user for a number between 1 and 100. I want the code to execute a loop until the user enters a correct number (between 1 and 100) and after that, it should execute the function `createGrid(parseInt(message))`;

My code is working when I type a correct number (between 1 and 100) and it shows the alert when the number is greater than 100 or less than 1, but then if try to enter another number between 1 and 100 it keeps showing the alert even if the number is correct.

There is definitely an error in my while loop but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
function clearGrid() {
    while (container.firstChild) {
        container.firstChild.remove();
    }

    let input;
    let message = prompt('Enter the number of squares for each side of the new grid:');

    if (parseInt(message) < 1 || parseInt(message) > 100) {
        input = false;

    while (input === false) {
        alert('Please enter a valid number between 1 and 100.');
        message = prompt('Enter the number of squares for each side of the new grid:');
    }

    if (parseInt(message) > 1 || parseInt(message) < 100) {
        createGrid(parseInt(message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your while loop checks for `input == false` and inside the loop there is nothing to set `input` to `true`, meaning there is nothing to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you need to have && not || how you have it setup is that if the int is bigger than 1 its good (meaning that it can go from 1 to 10000000000) or it could be (100- -10000000000) meaning you have all the numbers optional.

also the 2 ifstatements, please just have the first and then else, its kinda confusing to look at 2 if statements that are doing the same thing.

here is what I would do

```
if ( 0 < parseInt(message) < 100) {
    createGrid(parseInt(message));
   
}
else{
    input = false;
    while (input === false) {
        alert('Please enter a valid number between 1 and 100.');
        message = prompt('Enter the number of squares for each side of the newgrid:');
} }
```

I cant see anything else wrong with the code, I think you might have not sent all the code here so here you go.

EDIT You are missing bracket on the if statement? are you not getting an error there?